# How to gell all categories of user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have two models: `User`, `Category`.

Each user can have one or more categories in table `User_categories`.

Also there is table `User` and `Categories`.

My relationship are:

**User**

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```

**Category**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

I try to get all categories of user throuth model `Category`:

```
User::where("id", $id)->with("country", "city", "categories")->first();
```

**Result:**

[image]

I try to get categories name:

```
@foreach($profile->categoriesPivot() as $item)
<span class="label label-default">{{$item->category()->name}}</span>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: you will need to define the `pivot` table name on the `belongsToMany` relationship as its not following convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to use many to many here, change relationship to:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

And pivot table name should be `category_user`

Comment: And how to call this?

Comment: I tried: `User::where("id", $id)->with("country", "city", "categoriesPivot")->first();`

Comment: When you'll fix the relationship and pivot table name, do this `User::with('categories')->find($id);`

Comment: It works, when how to get data from Pivot table I mean name of category? I tried: `@foreach($profile->categoriesPivot()->category() as $item)`

Comment: @Darama just iterate over the collection with something like `@foreach ($user->categories as $category)  {{ $category->name }}  @endforeach`

Comment: If to do as you suggest it return me `BelongsToMany` model

Comment: I added pic in question

Answer (score 1):

Since you have set the relationship in the user model, the right way to do it would be:

`// Get all categories from user by $id
   $categories = User::find($id)->categories()->get();`

Answer (score 0):

This case define for One-To-Many

Define in your `User` model

```
public function getAllCategoriesAttribute()
{
    return Category::where('user_id', $this->id)->get();
}
```

And try in your Controller

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
dd($user->allCategories);
```

Updated: Above source code in One-To-Many case

---

This case define for Many-To-Many

Define in your `User` model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_user', 'user_id', 'category_id');
}
```

And in your Controller

```
dd($user->categories);
```

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Sorry I don't see Many-To-Many Eloquent. I've updated my source code.